# TableRenderer colors whole Table (JTable)

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, cell

I have got a small problem.

My TableRenderer is supposed to color empty cells, instead the whole JTable gets colored.

I looked up "coloring single cells" on the internet and tried some ideas, but they didnt work.

here is my Renderer:

```
public class TransTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if(value != null)
        {
            String[] values = value.toString().split("\\t s-p-l-i-t");
            if(values[0].isEmpty())
            {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            this.setText(values[0]);
            this.setToolTipText(values[1]);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

...and thats how is set the Renderer:

```
JTable jt = new JTable();
jt.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TransTableRenderer());
```

i appreciate every answer! thank you in advance :)

Comment: your splitting looks mysterious . i dont think its working right

Comment: my splitting actually works :D didnt find a way to do it better

Comment: The important point is that a single renderer component is reused for all the cells in a particular column, so you have to manually reset the color etc.. at each call .

Comment: Well thank you Berger, that actually works :))